# Uploading a 4kb file with MAMP

Tags: php, file-upload, mamp

I'm trying to upload a file with MAMP (1.9.4 on OS X).
I use this script [I found here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php) :

Here is the form code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

And the `uploader.php` code:

```
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

The `uploads` folder does exist but when I submit my form, I get the following error:

```
There was an error uploading the file, please try again!
```

How can I resolve this?
Thanks,

Regards.

EDIT: In phpinfo (5.3.2), File upload is 'on'.

Comment: `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['error']` holds an error code in case of failure. What does it say?

Comment: I put a "echo $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'];" and it returned '0'.

Comment: Could you do a `var_dump($_FILES);`, please?

Comment: [Manual says](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php): *If filename [...] cannot be moved [...] `move_uploaded_file()` will return `FALSE`. Additionally, a warning will be issued.* What says your warning?

Comment: @Linus Kleen: I have no warning;
@Matt: The 'var_dump' returned 'NULL'

Comment: @Thierry: And that's after the form was submitted with a file selected, yes?

Comment: @Matt: Yes. When I perform the post, the 'uploader.php' echoes 'NULL' for the 'var_dump($_FILES);' instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!

instead using `$_FILES`, I tried and used `$HTTP_POST_FILES`.
And instead `move_uploaded_file`, I used the copy `function`.

Can anyone give me an explanation?

Thanks.